# Form is not sending all parameters on POST in Firefox

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I have a simple html form that sends info to my mail using PHP.

When I use Chrome, all parameters are send correctly, but when I try sending the form with Firefox, the  value from select tag is not send to my mail. If I check the header with LiveHeaders, I can see that the parameter is not in header.

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="mail.php" id="signup"> 

<input class="ime1" name="ime1" placeholder="Oseba 1: Ime in Priimek" type="text">
<input class="starost1" name="starost1" placeholder="Starost" type="text"><br/>

<b>City</b>
<select id="problem" name="problem">
    <option id=""  value="1">London</option>                      
    <option id=""  value="2">Ljubljana</option>
    <option id=""  value="3">Belgrade</option>
    <option id=""  value="4">Havana</option>
</select>
</form>
```

PHP Code, mail.php:

```
<?php
$name1 = $_POST['ime1'];
$starost1 = $_POST['starost1'];
$problem= isset($_POST['problem']) ? $_POST['problem'] : null; 

$formcontent=
        "REZERVACIJA \n\n"
        . "1. OSEBA:  $name1 \n"        
        . "                  $starost1 let \n "
        . "                  $problem \n ";        


$recipient = "cyc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Rezervacija";
$mailheader = "From: asd@sf.com \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

TO sum up: Mozilla is not sending select(name="problem") in header when submiting my form.

Comment: Most probably the missing `;` at the end of `$problem \n "`

Comment: I have the semicolon in my original code, just made a mistake here.. corrected. Tnx anyway!

Comment: maybe cause you have the same id four times even if it is null.

Comment: I'm not sure but the repeated Id's could cause this

Comment: I deleted tne null id's.. still nothing

Comment: I tested your code and it came in fine (minus the select) using FF `25.0.1` are you trying to run this via `localhost` or WWW?

Comment: have you tried doing this , `(isset($_POST['problem']) ? $_POST['problem'] : '');`

Comment: Fred- it didn't make any difference

Comment: I fully tested your code this time, and it might be because your form (at least from your posted code) doesn't have a submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` try adding that and try again.

Comment: You have unclosed HTML tags (`<div>`, `<center`), maybe the version of FireFox you're using doesn't like that and is creating the HTML structure improperly.

Comment: Drixon, thank you!! It didn't work via localhost, but it works via server. Can u please explain what could cause that. Thanks again!!

Comment: i added `input` and works perfectly.

Comment: @user2375263 if you are using windows try to hard refresh.. CTRL + F5

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary operator is incorrect it should enclosed with parenthesis to avoid confusion

so it should be like this:

```
(isset($_POST['problem']) ? $_POST['problem'] : '')
```

or

```
(isset($_POST['problem'])) ? $_POST['problem'] : ''
```

Comment: tnx for answer, but i tried this, and there was no difference. I just had to launch the project via server, it doesnt work via localhost

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
    <form method="POST" action="mail.php" id="signup"> 

<input class="ime1" name="ime1" placeholder="Oseba 1: Ime in Priimek" type="text">
<input class="starost1" name="starost1" placeholder="Starost" type="text"><br/>

<b>City</b>
<select id="problem" name="problem">
    <option id="a"  value="London">London</option>                      
    <option id="b"  value="Ljubljana">Ljubljana</option>
    <option id="c"  value="Belgrade">Belgrade</option>
    <option id="d"  value="Havana">Havana</option>
</select>
</form>
```

PHP code